# run Hourly Scheduler using gocron

Tags: go

How to run function hourly specific minute using gocron?

i tried two code one is very dirty and one is not working.

the dirty code:

```
    loc, _ := time.LoadLocation("Asia/Seoul")
    s := gocron.NewScheduler(loc)

    _, err = s.Every(1).Day().At("0:30").Do(schduler)
    _, err = s.Every(1).Day().At("1:30").Do(schduler)
    _, err = s.Every(1).Day().At("2:30").Do(schduler)
    _, err = s.Every(1).Day().At("3:30").Do(schduler)
    _, err = s.Every(1).Day().At("4:30").Do(schduler)
    _, err = s.Every(1).Day().At("5:30").Do(schduler)
    _, err = s.Every(1).Day().At("6:30").Do(schduler)
    _, err = s.Every(1).Day().At("7:30").Do(schduler)
    _, err = s.Every(1).Day().At("8:30").Do(schduler)
    _, err = s.Every(1).Day().At("9:30").Do(schduler)
    _, err = s.Every(1).Day().At("10:30").Do(schduler)
    _, err = s.Every(1).Day().At("11:30").Do(schduler)
    _, err = s.Every(1).Day().At("12:30").Do(schduler)
    _, err = s.Every(1).Day().At("13:30").Do(schduler)
    _, err = s.Every(1).Day().At("14:30").Do(schduler)
    _, err = s.Every(1).Day().At("15:30").Do(schduler)
    _, err = s.Every(1).Day().At("16:30").Do(schduler)
    _, err = s.Every(1).Day().At("17:30").Do(schduler)
    _, err = s.Every(1).Day().At("18:30").Do(schduler)
    _, err = s.Every(1).Day().At("19:30").Do(schduler)
    _, err = s.Every(1).Day().At("20:30").Do(schduler)
    _, err = s.Every(1).Day().At("21:30").Do(schduler)
    _, err = s.Every(1).Day().At("22:30").Do(schduler)
    _, err = s.Every(1).Day().At("23:30").Do(schduler)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error scheduling task:", err)
        return
    }
    s.StartAsync()
```

not working code:

```
_, err = s.Every(1).Hour().Minute(30).Do(runHourlyScheduler)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.Every(1).Hour()` and then chain it with `.StartAt()` and fill the argument with any `time.Time` object that has minutes set to `30`.

With that, the scheduler will run for minutes `30` every hour.

```golang
loc, _ := time.LoadLocation("Asia/Seoul")
s := gocron.NewScheduler(loc)

// construct start at in minute 30
now := time.Now()
nextSchedule := time.Date(now.Year(), now.Month(), now.Day(), now.Hour(), 30, 0, 0, now.Location())

_, err := s.Every(1).Hour().StartAt(nextSchedule).Do(schduler)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error scheduling task:", err)
    return
}

s.StartAsync()
```

Comment: Is this Scheduler will run tommorrow too? or only for one day?

Comment: it will run every 1 hour every day. not limited to today.

Answer (score 0):

```
if cfg.JobEnabled {
    go func() {
        if err := service./*ServiceName*/(); err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error: %s", err.Error())
        }
    }()

    syncEmployeesSb := gocron.NewScheduler()
    syncEmployeesSb.Every(30).Minutes().Do(func() {
        if err := service./*ServiceName*/(); err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error: %s", err.Error())
        }
    })
    go syncEmployeesSb.Start()
} // Implement the launch separately
```

Answer (score -2):

To run an hourly scheduler using gocron in Go programming language, you can use the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/go-co-op/gocron"
)

func task() {
    fmt.Println("Running task...")
}

func main() {
    // Create a new scheduler
    scheduler := gocron.NewScheduler()

    // Schedule task to run every hour
    _, err := scheduler.Every(1).Hour().Do(task)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error scheduling task:", err)
        return
    }

    // Start the scheduler
    scheduler.Start()

    // Wait for the scheduler to finish
    <-scheduler.Done()
}
```

In the code above, we import the gocron package and define a task function that will be executed by the scheduler. We create a new scheduler and schedule the task to run every hour using the Every(1).Hour().Do(task) method. We then start the scheduler using scheduler.Start() and wait for it to finish using <-scheduler.Done(). If there are any errors while scheduling the task, we print an error message and exit.

You can customize the schedule as needed by using other methods provided by gocron, such as Every(2).Hours() to run the task every two hours or At("10:00").Do(task) to run the task at a specific time of day.

Comment: can i set the minute? i want to run an hourly scheduler not exact time. 
like 9:30, 10:30 .... 23:30

Comment: this answer reads like it was written by ChatGPT and doesn't answer the question.